The use of its vs. their for numbers
The title of my work is:
"RANKING FUZZY NUMBERS AND ITS APPLICATIONS TO FUZZY
DECISION-MAKING PROBLEMS"
Kindly suggest whether the word  "its" needs to be changed to "their"
as grammarly, and a few other AI grammar detection softwares found no issue with "its" in the title. Which word shall be more suitable? Thanks in advance!

application should be singular. Perhaps you could reorder:  xxxx-ranking of fuzzy-numbers in decision-making where xxxx is the ranking approach taken.   The little preposition in  conveys the idea of "application".


RANKING FUZZY NUMBERS AND ITS APPLICATIONS TO FUZZY DECISION-MAKING PROBLEMS

This topic is too technical for me, and hence I give two scenarios.
If we are looking at how fuzzy numbers apply to fuzzy decision-making problems, we use their as NUMBERS is plural.
If we are looking at how the process of ranking fuzzy numbers applies to fuzzy decision-making problems, we use its.
